# Widening the scope of an LDAP query to Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to use LDAP to authenticate against the company Active Directory. ADExplorer shows me that the directory is set up in the manner:

```
Active Directory Explorer
-- MyCompany.com
 +- DC=MyCompany, DC=com
  +- OU=Domain Controllers
  +- OU=MyCompany Locations
   +- OU=BR
   +- OU=CA
   +- OU=DE
   |+- OU=Munich
   |+- OU=MyTown
   ||+- OU=Users & Computers
   |||+- OU=Users
   ||||+- CN=Firstname1 Lastname1
   ||||+- CN=Firstname2 Lastname2
```

When I select a particular user, myself for example, I see the AD path is in the form below.

> OU=Users,OU=Users & Computers,OU=MyTown,OU=DE,OU=MyCompany
>   Locations,DC=MyCompany,DC=com

I set up the LDAP options in my application's config.php as follows:

```
$ldap_base_dn_ar[0]['attribute_name'] = 'ou';
$ldap_base_dn_ar[0]['attribute_value'] = 'Users';

$ldap_base_dn_ar[1]['attribute_name'] = 'ou';
$ldap_base_dn_ar[1]['attribute_value'] = 'Users & Computers';

$ldap_base_dn_ar[2]['attribute_name'] = 'ou';
$ldap_base_dn_ar[2]['attribute_value'] = 'MyTown';

$ldap_base_dn_ar[3]['attribute_name'] = 'ou';
$ldap_base_dn_ar[3]['attribute_value'] = 'DE';

$ldap_base_dn_ar[4]['attribute_name'] = 'ou';
$ldap_base_dn_ar[4]['attribute_value'] = 'MyCompany Locations';

$ldap_base_dn_ar[5]['attribute_name'] = 'dc';
$ldap_base_dn_ar[5]['attribute_value'] = 'MyCompany';

$ldap_base_dn_ar[6]['attribute_name'] = 'dc';
$ldap_base_dn_ar[6]['attribute_value'] = 'com';
```

This works but I suspect that it will only work for users in MyTown and country.

How would I change this to allow LDAP authentication from any town in any country?

---

From Gabriel Luci's comments:

> You say "I suspect" - have you test that? Maybe it already works the way you want.

I don't have a foreign login at the moment. I'll get one set up or get someone to test it.

> But you should only have to specify OU=MyCompany Locations since everything is under that.

```
$ldap_base_dn_ar[0]['attribute_name'] = 'ou';
$ldap_base_dn_ar[0]['attribute_value'] = 'MyCompany Locations';

$ldap_base_dn_ar[1]['attribute_name'] = 'dc';
$ldap_base_dn_ar[1]['attribute_value'] = 'MyCompany';

$ldap_base_dn_ar[2]['attribute_name'] = 'dc';
$ldap_base_dn_ar[2]['attribute_value'] = 'com';
```

If I cut the LDAP options down as shown above authentication fails.

Comment: You say "I suspect" - have you test that? Maybe it already works the way you want. But you should only have to specify `OU=MyCompany Locations` since everything is under that.

Comment: Thanks, @GabrielLuci. See the update.

Comment: How is your application doing the authentication?

Comment: The user enters the username / password at the login screen and the application makes the LDAP request using that username/pw combination. It's a commercial PHP app ([DaDaBiK](http://dadabik.com) low code web application builder) with Ioncube encryption so I doubt I can figure out what it's doing.

Comment: When searching LDAP, you can specify a "scope", which can be set to "one level" to search only the one level, or "subtree" to search all levels below. Does it give you the option to set the scope?

Comment: I can't see how to set the scope in my application. I've asked the developer and will report back.